# understanding Android application cache files

Tags: android

I understand that the cache is data that is temporarily stored from a specific app.  Opening /data/data/com.blah.blah/cache/ using a root file explorer reveals these cache files to me.  I am able to open and view those that are an image, but when opening a non-image cache file - usually with a text editor - I get a bunch of Chinese looking characters... I know that basically the apps cache is only viewable by said app, but is there any way to convert file to a human readable text file?

Comment: It likely depends on the app that stored that file. The only difference between caching a file and storing a file is the folder and the visibility of the file. If your app com.blah.blah caches test files, opening it will show text. If your app uses binary files, it will look like a weird character.

Comment: So say that the folder contains files with the names 4532.0, 4533.0, etc, and opening them gives me the weird characters... How to read the data? Would I have to disassemble the apk to find how it stores it's cache and go from there?

Answer (score 2):

> but is there any way to convert file to a human readable text file?

Contact the developers of the app and ask them.

There are [a dizzying roster of possible file formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats), even among "standard" types. Any given computer program might use one of those file formats, or invent their own, or use one of those formats but encrypt the file, etc. There is no requirement that all computer files contain human-readable material. For all we know, the developers of this app are storing random numbers in these files, specifically to confuse people who try to reverse-engineer their stored data.